# Using ESM2 to predict GRAB sensor performance

Tags: transformer

I am an undergrad working in a neuroscience lab, and my PI has tasked me with using ESM2(https://github.com/facebookresearch/esm) to predict GPCR Activation Based (GRAB) sensor performance for in vivo imaging of neuromodulation, basically predicting the fluorescence of the sensor (dF/F). I am very new to machine learning, so I am lost on how to do this. My PI said that I should find a paper which uses ESM2 or another LLM to predict fluorescence and use that as a base to go off of, but I cannot find one at all, and after a quick search my PI couldn't either. The closest thing I could find is this, but I don't really understand it. https://www.kaggle.com/code/mnicatavares/enzyme-mutation-effect-prediction-using-esm2/notebook
I found some articles about the optimization of GRAB sensors but they don't seem to use LLM's for predicting performance. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very helpful.